# how to use sqlite query select using pass variables?

Tags: sqlite

I want to use this code.

using python2 sqlte3

con=sq.connect()

cur=con.cursor()

---

instead of under code

cur.execute("SELECT id, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(**37**) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )    * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(**127**) ) + sin( radians(**37**) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance
 FROM TEST_TABLE HAVING distance < 5
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;")

---

I want to change this.

val1=input()

val2=input()

cur.execute("SELECT id, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(**val2**) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )    * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(**val1**) ) + sin( radians(**val2**) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance
 FROM TEST_TABLE HAVING distance < 5
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;")

---

how can i pass val1,val2?

like this

cur.execute("select * from tablename where a=? and b=?",('a','b'))

i tried this code

cur.execute("select ? from tablename ",('a'))

This causes a syntax error. also I can't find it with Google search....

help me.. thank you for reading.

Comment: This is pretty vague, what language are you using to submit queries?

Comment: @jackarms It looks like Python, but even then this question is vague, and probably a duplicate.

Comment: @jackarms I apologize for not having an accurate question. my question..

SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(127) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TEST_TABLE HAVING distance < 5
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5; in this query... I want to store and pass 127 and 37 as variables.

Comment: You need to provide more context, please edit the original question.

Comment: @jackarms i edit my question .. how about this?

Comment: Does it work WITHOUT the parameter substitutions? Because when I tried your initial SQL, sqlite3 says `no such function: acos`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cos, sin, etc work with your copy of sqlite3, you'll need to do **something** like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE distance < 5
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;", (val2, val1, val2))
```

I say "something like" because your original SQL does not work.  It has a `HAVING` in the criteria, which is only good if you have a `GROUP BY` clause.  So `WHERE` is the way to go.

It's quite interesting that sqlite3 allows you to use the name of calculated fields in the `WHERE` clause.  Some database engines don't allow this, and make you recalculate it in the where clause because ... I don't know why.

So here's a minimal working snippet that illustrates how to do multiple parameter substitution:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example2.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute ('''CREATE TABLE test_table ( id number, distance number, lat number, lng number ) ''')
c.execute ("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1, 1, -36.862, 174.725)")
c.execute ("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (6, 6, -41.244, 174.621)")

conn.commit()


val1 = 3
val2 = 5

# this is the line you're most interested in:
c.execute("SELECT id, lat + ? x, lng + ?, lat * lng * ? distance FROM TEST_TABLE where distance < 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;", (val2, val1, val2) )

print c.fetchone()
```

One more thing - this won't work:

```
cur.execute("select ? from tablename ",('a'))
```

You can't use parameter substitution for field names.